# How to get the proper class during a cast from JSON in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a very simple class

```
export class Foo {

    name: string;

    index: number;

    toFullString(): string {
        return `${this.name} | ${this.index}`;
    }
}
```

I get elements of this class from a server and cast json to this class:

```
.map(response => response.json() as Foo)
```

Now what happens is that after I call `toFullString()` method it fails since this is not the "real" `Foo` object as it would be in say C#.

So what is the proper way of achieving real `Foo` object, preferably without the need of writing your own constructors and so on.

The type safety in TypeScript is a joke sometimes really.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Comment: Either you're going to have to write your own constructor or you'll have to take your returned obejcts and append the function (technically legal JS) with `for(let obj of responseObjects) { obj['toFullString'] = function ... }`.

One you don't want, and the other is a little sketchy.

Comment: @chimmi this does not seem to be a duplicate. I already can cast, that's not the problem. The problem is that ordinary casting is not enough to get the "real" class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you're going to have to write your own constructor or you'll have to take your returned obejcts and append the function (technically legal JS) with `for(let obj of responseObjects) { obj['toFullString'] = function ... }`. One you don't want, and the other is a little sketchy.

The constructor method you have already seen but I'll repeat here:

```
constructor(public name, public index) {
    this.name = name;
    this.index = index;
}
```

You could also do it in the map which is the same thing.

```
masterFoo: Foo = new Foo();

mapFoo(responseObject: any) {
    <...>
    responseObject['toFullString'] = masterFoo.toFullString;
    <...>
  }
```

The auto mapping works for data objects only, and it's a limitation due to JS being the underlying language of it all.

Here's a plunker demonstrating appending the function to a Plain Old JavaScript Object:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BBOthl0rzjfEq3UjD68I?p=preview

Comment: That looks like quite hacky unfortunately, so I guess I'll stick with constructor or ordinary mapping if nothing better exists... Though I suppose there are some sort of AutoMapper for TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the Object and give it the JSON values.

```
.map(res => this.onResponse(res))
```

-

```
function onResponse(res:any){
    this.foo = new Foo();
    this.foo.name = res['name'];
    ...
}
```

Or give the JSON values to the constructor of Foo

```
this.foo = new Foo(res['name'], ...);
```

Comment: Well, I wanted to avoid it, to do things automatically somehow. It's a lot of tedious work...