# Property does not exist on type Object in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ionic2

I'm using Ionic and Angular2 Typescript. When View is rendered I call the function `retrieveNotifications` in the file *dashboard.ts* but I get an error:

> ```
> Error: Error at /home/invicta/Desktop/newauth/.tmp/pages/dashboard/dashboard.ts:36:34 
> Property 'notifications' does not exist on type '{}'
> ```

---

```
//dashboard.ts
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.retrieveNotifications();
}


retrieveNotifications() {
    this.user.retrieveNotifications().then(data = > {
        // when do console.log here and typeof(), data is object and it has notifications array
        this._notifications = data.notifications;
    })
}
```

Then in file *user-data.ts* which is declare like `public user: UserData` is function:

```
//user-data.ts -> provider
retrieveNotifications() {
    var token = this.authservice.getUserToken();
    return new Promise(resolve = > {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        this.http.get(this.mainUrl + '/api/v1/notification', {
            headers: headers
        }).subscribe(data = > {
            if (data.status === 200)
                resolve(data.json());
            else
                resolve(false);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510795/cannot-call-a-function-on-an-element-inside-ngfor-angular2/40511035#40511035

Answer (score 10):

Try to bypass the error with:

```
this._notifications = data['notifications'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try another way to bypass the error with:

```
return new Promise().then(()=>{
     return data;
})
```